# PHP buttons in table without loading a separate page

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to learn PHP and mySQL by building a table. I have the table displayed just fine and the buttons are where they should be. What I'm having trouble with though is making the buttons do what I want. I know most of the time you have an index.php or whatever and then when you try to edit something, it goes to edit.php. I don't want to do that, I want to have the row in the table turn into text boxes that I can edit. Is that possible?

Bonus question, I want to have another button that when clicked, adds a row beneath the selected row to add comments. Then when the button is clicked again that row goes away. Is there an easy(ish) way to do that?

I would post code, but nothing I have is working yet so there's not much benefit. I don't really know where to even begin on these two issues.

Comment: You'll want to use javascript to perform actions client side. If you need to retrieve data as well send an AJAX request to a PHP script.

Comment: I've been trying to stick with only PHP/HTML/SQL, is that not reasonable to do for this request? I'll start looking into javascript and ajax though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is called Javascript/Ajax. But there are frameworks for your case: Take a look at [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/), that brings everything you need to create apps without any page reload.

Comment: Is there a realistic way to do it without those? I get that Javascript/Ajax are the accepted way to do these kinds of things, but (and correct me if this is a bad way to do things) I'm trying to learn to build this stuff from the ground up, so in this case only using PHP/HTML/SQL, then once it's working I'll add Javascript/Ajax. Maybe that's just my ignorance though?

Comment: No, there isn't other way, because PHP is running on your server. So, if you want to manipulate data on the server, you need to send data from the client (e.g. your browser) to the server. Javascript can send data in the "background" and can interact with the result received from the server. If you don't using Javascript, there isn't anything else such as a - page reload or form send action - that can send data to your server (sorry about my bad englisch!)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks for the clarification!